# Regarding log4j properties and maxfilesize

Tags: java, log4j

I m a using log4j version 1.2 in my Java application.

I have set maxfilesize appender to 5 MB and Mac backup index to 100. As per my understanding after reaching to 5mb log4j should make a new file. But in my application it continues to write logs in same file and when I restart my application then it starts making a new file from 0kb. Is it the normal behavior of log4j or something wrong with the configurations?

P. S - I am using rolling appender and log4j. properties

Comment: you need use a RollingFileAppender

Comment: I am using a rolling file appender only but the behavior is same in 2 applications. That's why I asked is the normal behavior of log4j?

Comment: show your log4j config file